# How to define a class template with reference type template parameter of template template parameter type

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to define a class template (hereafter called `C`) which takes a reference to an object of an to-be instantiated class template (hereafter called `S`) as template parameter. The objective is that `C` can be fully instantiated with one template argument.

`S` is a class template on its own which has one integral type template parameter. The `C` class template shall be instantiated using a reference to an object of any instantiation of `S`.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```cpp
template<int I> struct S {
    int get() { return 42 + I; }
};

//        ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓  my desperate attempt
template< typename S<int I>::template & n>
struct C {
    int get() {
        return n.get();
    }
};

S<42> s;

int main()
{
    C<s> c;
    return c.get();
}
```

The compiler I am using supports GNU++11 or older.

Comment: `s` would need to be `constexpr` in order to be allowed as a template parameter (among other issues).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That would be true only if the parameter wasn't a reference (which wouldn't work pre-C++20 anyway).

Comment: This doesn't look doable in C++11. Would be simple in C++17.

Comment: This is the best I got, which admittedly isn't very close at all: https://godbolt.org/z/1P5aEEMh9

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, unfortunately this does not use the object of `S<42>`. Thank you for the effort anyways!

Comment: The simplicity of C++17 that @HolyBlackCat mentioned: `template<auto &n> struct C {...};`

Comment: It sucks to be stuck with old versions of the language standard. 

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It wouldn't, as long as the parameter is not a const reference.

Comment: Why do you need a reference to an object of `S<42>` as a template argument? Wouldn't the type be enough? `C` could store the object internally, or take a reference to it in it's constructor. Seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @super because the object of `S<42>` has non-static member variables in the "real" software. This is just a minimal example.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It is, try it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That's because you made `S<42> s` `constexpr`. Remove `constexpr` and it will work.

Comment: @user5534993 That doesn't answer any of my two questions. Both letting `C` hold the object internally or passing a reference to `C`s constructor are valid options in that scenario. So why does it have to be a reference passed as a template parameter?

Comment: The way to get around this kind of limitation in early versions of the language is normally to use `auto c = make_c(s);` approach. Easily doable here without passing any template parameters, just a reference to the instance of `s`.

Comment: @super, yes you are correct, this is an *XY problem*. The reason why the reference to the object of `S<42>` needs to be passed as template parameter is, that `C` has a static member function which operates on that object. This is missing in my example. Also my objective was to have *only one* template parameter for `C` as this should either be a reference to an object of `S` or an integer ([more details](https://godbolt.org/z/cv1EYW7d8)). But this is not possible with C++11, as this would require `auto` as placeholder, I guess. I will have to reconsider my design. Thanks for your questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++17, you might do

```
template<int I> struct S { int get() { return 42 + I; } };

template <auto& n>
struct C;

template <int I, S<I>& n>
struct C<n>
{
    int get() { return n.get(); }
};

S<42> s;

int main()
{
    C<s> c;
    return c.get();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xjWbqbfso).

Before C++17, `template <auto& n> struct C;` has to be replaced. for example by

`template <typename T, T& n> struct C;`

```
template <typename T, T& n>
struct C;

template <int I, S<I>& n>
struct C<S<I>, n>
{
    int get() { return n.get(); }
};

S<42> s;

#define AUTO(x) decltype(x), x

int main()
{
    C<S<42>, s> c;
    // C<AUTO(s)> c;
    return c.get();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3Yofjzv3r)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that I know in C++11 that will allow you to change just the template parameters to do what you want. What you can do though is not have a non-type template parameter, but just a type, and add a constructor to `C` that takes the reference to the desired object as a parameter:

```
template<typename T>
struct C {
    C(T &t): t(t) {}
    int get() {
        return t.get();
    }
private:
    T &t;
};
```

Then you could declare `c` as follows:

```
C<decltype(s)> c(s);
```

However, it is of course not so nice to have to repeat yourself like that, so the trick is to make a templated function that will construct a `C` of the right type for you:

```
template<typename T>
C<T> make_C(T &t) {
    return C<T>(t);
}
```

And then you can write:

```
auto c = make_C(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer. But maybe this helps somebody who stumbled upon this question *or* even help somebody to actually find the answer.

In contrast to the original question I added the static member variable `S.i`.

```cpp
template<int I> struct S {
    static constexpr int i = I;
    int get() { return 42 + I; }
};

template<int I, S<I>& n> struct C
{
    int get() {
        return n.get();
    }
};

S<42> s;

int main()
{
    C<s.i, s> c;
    return c.get();
}
```

This is not the answer, because still *two template arguments*  are required in order to instantiate the class template `C`.

This [compiles with C++11](https://godbolt.org/z/M5Md4KasP).